# SIM5360A - HTTP bad request

Tags: http, arduino, embedded, esp32

I'm developing a device with an ESP32 connected through a level shifter to a SIM5360**A**.
The system is supposed to make a periodic HTTP post with it's sensor readings.

Even though I have a working setup with a SIM5360**E** breakout board, when I shifted to a custom PCB with a SIM5360**A** (because of carrier frequency), I'm not able of making an HTTP post/get.
Using a server hosted in AWS and doing a TCPDump, I detected that before the GET payload the SIM5360**A** inserts two spurious characters (0x01 0xF0).

The commands I'm sending to the modem are:

```
AT+CIPOPEN=0,"TCP","XX.XXX.XXX.XXX",80

AT+CIPSEND=0,39
GET /login HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>
Host: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
```

Using Wireshark to analyze the query on the server side, the data received is:
{0x01} {0xF0} GET ....

Those two characters confuse the apache server (and Wireshark) which doesn't interpret this as a HTTP message driving a 400: Bad Request.

I verified using PostMan that the query is correct. I also use the exact same firmware on my SIM5360E breakout successfully.

Using a scope I verified that the two characters are dumped into the UART channel by the SIM5360A and not by the level shifter or the ESP32.

I wanted to do a firmware upgrade on the SIM5360**A** but SIMCOM only has the 'E' firmware update available on it's website (just including this consideration for if someone has the firmware update for this version).

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Bests